# Post Title List on home page with time

Tags: posts

I am unable to find this coding on internet tuturial and highly appreciate for this answer with details.

I want to show latest post on home page like this

1st Post title - posted 4 minutes ago
2nd post title - posted 2 days ago
3rd post title - posted 1 year ago

Comment: There are tons of code you can find here. Have you performed a search?

Answer (score 1):

In the main loop in index, to display the date like you are asking use:

```
<?php printf( _x( '%s ago', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?>
```

You can read more about it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff